# The following equation stems from Maxwell thermodynamic relations, I need to reduce it to the ideal gas law?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, physics, mathematical-physics

I have the following equation;

$$TS-PV =\alpha\cdot N\cdot K_B\cdot \left(\frac NV\right)^\frac23\cdot e^{\frac{2S}{3N\cdot K_b}}$$

which i have to reduce to the [Ideal gas Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law);

$$PV = NK_bT$$
I have been given the equation derived from Maxwell thermodynamic relations.  The issue is that the exponential must be reduced and the only method is to get the $\ln()$ across the entire equation. I then have $\ln()$ and to cancel I need to get the exponential  across the equation, but then I will have the exponential again and the cycle continues!

Regarding the entropy, S, they should cancel on both sides of the equation.

Comment: are there any other relations given which might help simplify things?

Comment: The original question given is explicitly:
~~~
It is a result of statistical mechanics that the internal energy of an ideal gas is 

$$E=E(S,V)=\alpha\cdot N\cdot K_B\cdot \left(\frac NV\right)^\frac23\cdot e^{\frac{2S}{3N\cdot K_b}}$$

where \alpha\ is a constant and the other symbols have their usual meanings. Show that the equation of state $$PV = NK_bT$$ follows from this equation.~~~
We know that the internal energy, E is dependent on S and V, and E = TS - PV
.Entropy, S. Volume, V. Energy, E. K_b is boltzmans constant and N is no. of particles. We are given no further information